# How to find file and get the URL when you have folder URL for share point online using REST?

Tags: c#, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I need to search for filename using REST API. All files will reside in one folder.

File Name Example :

DOC_34556
DOC_35646

I will search using this name and if the file is found i need to get the URL of that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below endpoint, if file exists, it'll return FileRef, otherwise null.

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('MyDoc3')/items?$select=FileRef&$filter=substringof(%27test2.docx%27,FileRef)
```

Comment: But here MyDoc3 will be the list right ? I can't pass folder path directly here i believe.